# Using np.where() with conditional on count in time loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'd like to use np.where() to specify a new df column, `df['avg_gain']`, with values from one of two other df columns, `df['avg_gain_0']` or `df['avg_gain_n']`, with the values used determined by the number of cycles in a time loop ('count' variable) as the conditional like below:

```
starttime = time.time()
count = 0 

def x(): 
    klines = client.get_klines(symbol='BTCUSDT', interval=Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE)
    df = pd.DataFrame(klines)
    df.columns = ['timestart', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'timeend']

    ...

    df['change'] = df.close.astype(float).diff()
    df['gain'] = np.where(df['change'] > 0, df['change'], 0)

    df['avg_gain_0'] = df['gain'].rolling(window=6, center=False).mean()
    df['avg_gain_n'] = ((float(df['avg_gain'].iloc[-1]) * 5) + df['gain']) / 6
    df['avg_gain'] = np.where(count = 0, df['avg_gain_0'], df['avg_gain_n'])

while True:
    try:
        x()
        count += 1
        time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

The `np.where()` function used for `df['gain']` works perfectly, but I am receiving a

> positional argument after keyword argument

error on the the `np.where()` function used for `df['avg_gain']`.

How can I resolve? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a `count` column in `df`? The first argument to `np.where()` needs to be array-like...

Comment: What's the `count=0` supposed to be doing?

Comment: The count variable is outside the dataframe, starting with a value of 0 and increasing by 1 each time the time/while loop is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call of *np.where* contains *count = 0* (with a **single** "="),
what is interpreted as a named (keyword) parameter.

In *np.where* the first argument is a **condition**.
So probably you should change this instruction to:

```
np.where(count == 0, df['avg_gain_0'], df['avg_gain_n'])
```

(**double** "=").